# Is it expensive? when using mongodb skip with _id

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I expected this query is not expensive

```
db.someCollection.find({}).skip(400000).limit(100);
```

Because, It would be indexed by "_id" so It could access to the document directly using index.

But this is probably wrong. by following mongodb doc,
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

why is the skip operation expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skip` with large argument can be expensive, because MongoDB have to query all docs that satisfies `.find` command and then skip 400k of them. The larger your docs size, the more expensive this operation will be.

`skip` can't take advantage of indexes, but you can build your indexes in the way that you will be able to do *some* queries very efficiently.

For example, you can do queries with pagination. Consider collection of posts, where `dt` is a date of creation:

```
{
 _id: ...
 dt: 123321123, // this is timestamp
 title: "asdf",
 ...
}
```

In this case if you want to to take next page of objects, you should use `dt` of last post to prefilter docs:

```
db.posts.find({dt: {gt: 123321123}}).sort({dt: 1}).limit(100)
```

Index by `_id` is also "some kind of" sequential, but it is not guaranteed. Think of `_id` as index which is suitable for accessing random documents, not sequences.

Comment: Im pretty sure _id is something you can relay on for sorting now, Its true that you can create a new field to sort by and index it but remember you are adding a line for each object, which in small scale is nothing but you should consider if you want it in a big collection. Also if you sort by date and have an option to save 2 objects at the same time notice to add gte instead go gt :) but its up to you

Comment: This answer is 5 years old, so maybe things have changed already. I'm not following update on MongoDB